# How to read only latest 7 days csv files from S3 bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure it out, how we can read only latest 7 days file from a folder which we have in s3 bucket using Spark Scala.

Directory which we have:

Assume for today's date(Date_1) we have 2 clients and 1-1 csv file

```
Source/Date_1/Client_1/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_1/Client_2/sample_1.csv
```

Tomorrow a new folder will generate and we will get as below:

```
Source/Date_2/Client_1/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_2/Client_2/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_2/Client_3/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_2/Client_4/sample_1.csv
```

NOTE: we expecting to have newer client data added on any date.

Likewise on 7th day we can have:

```
Source/Date_7/Client_1/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_7/Client_2/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_7/Client_3/sample_1.csv
Source/Date_7/Client_4/sample_1.csv
```

So, now if we get 8th day data, We need to discard the Date_1 folder to get read.

How we can do this while reading csv files using spark scala from s3 bucket?
I am trying to read the whole  **"source/*"** folder so that we should not miss if any client is getting added any time/day.

Comment: Can you share a few details such as (1) Are you using AWS Glue?  (2) What is Date format? (3) Is this path is partitionBy or normal path like directory/subdirectoty ? (4) the final csv file name is always same ?

Comment: 1: No just getting file in S3 bucket and from there reading the files directly
2: Date Format- "20211221" (Today's date as example, 21st Dec 2021)
3: Normal path like directory/subdirectory
4 : final file name should be depends upon client name appended with date, example (Client_1_20211221, Client_2_20211221 for today's date, similarly for next day date part will change -- Client_1_20211222, Client_2_20211222 )

Comment: Are you partitioning your data at the time of saving? I believe you are doing it based on the folder structure that I see... can you please confirm?

Comment: No, I am trying to same the data in Overwrite mode, The requirement for me is to calculate in basis of max 7 days older data and save in the table. So, No Partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it. One of the ways is mentioned below:
You can extract the Date from Path and the filter is based on the 7 Days.

Below is a code snippet for pyspark, the same can be implemented in Spark with Scala.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
 
#Calculate date 7 days before date
>>> lastDate = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-7)
>>> lastDate = int(lastDate.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

# Source Path
>>> srcPath = "s3://<bucket-name>/.../Source/"
>>> df1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(srcPath + "*/*").withColumn("Date", split(regexp_replace(input_file_name(), srcPath, ""),"/")[0].cast("long"))
>>> df2 = df1.filter(col("Date") >= lit(lastDate))
```

There are few things that might change in your final implementation, such as Index value [0] that might differ if the path structure is different and the last, the condition >= that can be > based on the requirement.